# Making an img sticky to the bottom of a div?

Tags: css, wordpress, image

I'm trying to place an img to the bottom of the outer div.

Sadly it is not working as the default styles from wordpress are making it impossible...

[My Project](http://iflorian.com/fwb_new/wordpress/store/products/hailey-jacket/)

The img I'm talking about is the small image on the left next to the big main one...

I would appreciate any help as this is already driving me crazy for hours!

Any help is appreciated!

Thanks

edit:
Here's a picture of what it should look like later:

[image: what it should look like]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would help if you posted a picture of what you want the end result to be, but to put an element at the bottom of a container the usual way is setting it's style to something like `position: absolute; bottom: 0` you can put a small value in `bottom:` to offset it a bit to match, you can then use `left` *or* `right`to set the offset with the other limits of the container.

Edit: I tried this code *in the img tag* with firebug, seemed to work like in your picture:

```css
element.style {
    bottom: 90px;
    position: absolute;
    right: 350px;
}
```

Comment: I added a picture! Thanks for the advice! I tried the position: absolute and the bottom css but that does not work, as I said wordpress is preventing a lot with their standard css which I can't disable because of the other content

Comment: Edited my answer with some code that seems to work well (I assume the big picture in the right will be fixed size.)